# Uploading python flask app to Heroku raises error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, heroku

While uploading my python flask app to Heroku I got the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dataclasses==0.8 (from -r /tmp/build_d980c139/requirements.txt (line 4)) (from versions: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for dataclasses==0.8 (from -r /tmp/build_d980c139/requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

Comment: pls post your requirements.txt since thats whats containing the problem.

Comment: appscript==1.1.2
chardet==4.0.0
click==8.0.1
dataclasses==0.8
docx2pdf==0.1.7
docx2txt==0.8
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
Flask==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
importlib-metadata==1.7.0
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.1
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
openpyxl==3.0.7
pdfminer3==2018.12.3.0
pycryptodome==3.10.1
PyPDF2==1.26.0
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
tqdm==4.61.1
typing-extensions==3.10.0.0
Werkzeug==2.0.1
xlwt==1.3.0
zipp==3.4.1

Comment: @Rahul Kumar what version of python are you running and what version is on heroku?

Comment: `dataclasses` is built-in, remove it from the requirements.txt file. See the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html

Comment: error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4t8ed_db/appscript/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4t8ed_db/appscript/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',

Comment: Now this error occured

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment). It will be more readable in question, and more people will see it.

Comment: now you have new error so you should create new question on new page. Error can means that one of modules (probably `appscript`) uses `C/C++` code and it has problem to compile it. You didn't show full error message so we can't see details. Sometimes C/C++ code may need Python source code in C/C++ or at least files `.h` which normally on Linux Ubuntu you can install with `apt install python-dev`

Comment: Instead of posting in the comments, please update your question with the information.

Answer (score 6):

Heroku installs the latest python version for your app. Currently I'm assuming it is installing python version 3.9.6. But from python 3.8.0 and onwards the dataclasses==0.8 is pre-built there. this external dataclasses library only exists from 0.1 - 0.6 version (which is showing in the error message) and has probably stopped upgrading as it exists in the pre-built now. Since it is not finding that particular 0.8 version, so it is throwing that not found error.

Now to solve the problem, There can be two ways-
The easy way is to remove dataclasses==0.8 from the requirement.txt and upload it.

Another way is to keep the dataclasses==0.8 in the requirement.txt and add another txt file called 'runtime.txt' in the same root directory where your requirement.txt is. And this line -`Python {yourspecifiedversion}`. this will tell Heroku which python version to install. You can select a python version that will match properly with all of your external libraries. but you will need to add 'dataclasses==0.8' if the python version is less 3.8.0

Specifying a python runtime on Heroku is in this link - [Specifying a Python Runtime](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes)